# REGEX: Match all instances of text, digits, + , _ and -, Between colons, which are NOT part of an URL

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-negation

I'd like to find and replace (with nothing) all instances of text between colons, like such:

:smile:
:thumbs_up:
:+1:
:-1:

but NOT if the colons are part of the url, like this URL for example:
http://pdf.reuters.com/htmlnews/htmlnews.asp?i=43059c3bf0e37541&u=urn:newsml:reuters.com:20190417:nPn5XHnXBa

As you can see, this URL has several colons and any such matches should be ignored.

The complete text can have some text before and after as well. In addition, these can also show up in succession, without any spaces in between. For example:

I was browsing and found this url :smile: http://pdf.reuters.com/htmlnews/htmlnews.asp?i=43059c3bf0e37541&u=urn:newsml:reuters.com:20190417:nPn5XHnXBa it's fantastic :smile::+1: Remember: don't forget to upvote!

I would expect the result to be:

I was browsing and found this url http://pdf.reuters.com/htmlnews/htmlnews.asp?i=43059c3bf0e37541&u=urn:newsml:reuters.com:20190417:nPn5XHnXBa it's fantastic Remember: don't forget to upvote!

I am using python regex module for my replacements.

My thinking is:
"Ok, I should find any URL and tell the regex to IGNORE any matches that are part of the URL"

So I have the regex to successfully match any URL as such:
(http[^\s]+)

This will find http and anything else until a non-whitespace character or newline, which would indicate the end of the URL.

I also have regex to match the text between (including) colons:
(:[\w+-]+:)

SO... I was hoping to use negative lookahead and combine these 2 like this:
(?!http[^\s]+)(:[\w+-]+:)

This is ALMOST perfect but it ends up matching these 2 parts of the URL:
:newsml:
and
:20190417:

How can I build this regex so that it matches everywhere in the text, EXCEPT if the colons are part of the URL?

Thanks a million!

PS. I've been using this awesome site to test my patterns... 
https://regexr.com/

Comment: First of all, try to make your question a [MCVE] as it's the de facto standard in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to have your regex match a URL pattern (captured in a group), *or* match something enclosed in `:`s, and then you can replace with the first captured group:

```
(https?://\S+)|:[\w+-]+:
```

replace with

```
\1
```

This ensures that URLS will stay where they are in the text (being matched and replaced with themselves), but the colon sections that you want to remove will be matched and replaced with nothing.

https://regex101.com/r/d7mM1s/2

Comment: GENIUS!! Worked perfectly! How come this does not repeat the first group (URL) multiple times, one for each :text: replaced? THANK YOU!!

Comment: Just one change I made was to escape the forward slashes in the first group:
(https?:\/\/\S+)|:[\w+-]+:

Comment: When a colon-section is matched, the first capture group will be empty, so the replaced string is the empty string.